# Need to add location to Google Places with API.. No way to add address?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have an android app that is adding places to the google Places API without problem.  My app also receives places added by other users.. To my dismay, I realized that when adding a place, there is no way to include an address, only a longitude and latitude.  I had suspected that Google would supply an address when the place was requested, but alas, the "vincinity" value is not included in the JSON returned from good on this location.

I suppose I could take the lat and lng and subsequently geocode (reverse-geocode?.. I can't ever keep them straight) the results myself, but was wondering if there was something I was overlooking.. I have read all the Places API docs through several times.. I thought if anyone knew a little trick, they would be on this website (of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'vicinity' parameter will only be returned after the Place Report Request has been moderated.

Currently only Place Report Requests submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places. We are still working on streamlining the moderation process to minimise spam, incorrect and duplicate place results.

The best option would be to reverse geocode the returned lat lng.

Comment: @Chris Green can you answer or shed light on this related question asking about add/edit/remove for places now that it's 4 years later (2016)? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208954/add-modify-delete-places-with-google-maps-api